# Parse custom tags In TSql

Tags: t-sql

I have the following data in the csv and want to parse the tag elements to get the column and values from the tag.

```
1,{
"StudentLocs":["US","Kric"],
"Student_Service":["NY Volunteer"],
"Student_Unit":["Band1"],
"Student_enZone":["UTC"],
"Student_Geoloc":["Ind"],
"StudentRegisted":[FT"],
"StudentGender":["Male"],
"StudentName":["Sam"]
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
StudentId SLocs  SService   SUnit SenZone SGeoloc SRegisted SGender SName
 1     US,Kric  NY Volunteer Band1 UTC     Ind       FT      Male    Sam
```

Thanks for your help in advance !

Comment: Please also share what you've tried so far.

Comment: That looks more like a json than sql, excuse my lack of knowledge.

Comment: This is not csv, this is Json. with SQL Server 2016 or higher, use the built in json support.

Comment: Is this one single string within one table column? And please tell us your SQL Server's version.

Comment: @Shnugo....This is CSV file

In this provided extract there are 2 columns first column is ID =1 other column is Tag which is in Parenthsis..and i using 2014 sqlsever version..

Tag =
{
"StudentLocs":["US","Kric"],
"Student_Service":["NY Volunteer"],
"Student_Unit":["Band1"],
"Student_enZone":["UTC"],
"Student_Geoloc":["Ind"],
"StudentRegisted":[FT"],
"StudentGender":["Male"],
"StudentName":["Sam"]
}

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use [DelimitedSplit8K](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function).

**Against a single value:**

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(8000) = 
'1,{
"StudentLocs":["US","Kric"],
"Student_Service":["NY Volunteer"],
"Student_Unit":["Band1"],
"Student_enZone":["UTC"],
"Student_Geoloc":["Ind"],
"StudentRegisted":[FT"],
"StudentGender":["Male"],
"StudentName":["Sam"]
}';

SELECT
  StudentId = MAX(CASE split.RN WHEN 0 THEN split.String END),
  SLocs     = MAX(CASE split.RN WHEN 2 THEN split.String END),
  SService  = MAX(CASE split.RN WHEN 3 THEN split.String END),
  SUnit     = MAX(CASE split.RN WHEN 4 THEN split.String END),
  SenZone   = MAX(CASE split.RN WHEN 5 THEN split.String END),
  SGeoloc   = MAX(CASE split.RN WHEN 6 THEN split.String END),
  SRegisted = MAX(CASE split.RN WHEN 7 THEN split.String END),
  SGender   = MAX(CASE split.RN WHEN 8 THEN split.String END),
  SName     = MAX(CASE split.RN WHEN 9 THEN split.String END)
FROM
(
  SELECT      RN = 0, String = SUBSTRING(@string,1,CHARINDEX(',',@String)-1)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT      s.ItemNumber, clean.string
  FROM        (VALUES(@string,CHARINDEX(',',@string))) AS f(String,B)
  CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(f.String,CHAR(10))  AS s
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('":',s.item)))         AS d(Pos)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(CHAR(13),s.item)))     AS v(E)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(
               s.item,d.Pos+3,v.E-d.Pos-5),'"','')))   AS clean(String)
  WHERE       d.Pos > 0
) AS split;
```

**Returns:**

```
SomeId      StudentId     SLocs        SService        SUnit  SenZone  SGeoloc  SRegisted  SGender  SName     
----------- ------------- ------------ --------------- ------ -------- -------- ---------- -------- ---------
1           1             US,Kric      NY Volunteer    Band1  UTC      Ind      FT         Male     Sam
```

**Against a table:**

```
-- Sample table
DECLARE @table TABLE (SomeId INT IDENTITY, String VARCHAR(8000));
INSERT @table (String) VALUES(
'1,{
"StudentLocs":["US","Kric"],
"Student_Service":["NY Volunteer"],
"Student_Unit":["Band1"],
"Student_enZone":["UTC"],
"Student_Geoloc":["Ind"],
"StudentRegisted":[FT"],
"StudentGender":["Male"],
"StudentName":["Sam"]
}'),
('1,{
"StudentLocs":["US","Chicago"],
"Student_Service":["Rock Star"],
"Student_Unit":["Band4"],
"Student_enZone":["XFS"],
"Student_Geoloc":["Ill"],
"StudentRegisted":[PT"],
"StudentGender":["Female"],
"StudentName":["Juliana"]
}');


SELECT t.SomeId, split.* 
FROM @table AS t
CROSS APPLY 
(
  SELECT
    StudentId = MAX(CASE split.RN WHEN 0 THEN split.String END),
    SLocs     = MAX(CASE split.RN WHEN 2 THEN split.String END),
    SService  = MAX(CASE split.RN WHEN 3 THEN split.String END),
    SUnit     = MAX(CASE split.RN WHEN 4 THEN split.String END),
    SenZone   = MAX(CASE split.RN WHEN 5 THEN split.String END),
    SGeoloc   = MAX(CASE split.RN WHEN 6 THEN split.String END),
    SRegisted = MAX(CASE split.RN WHEN 7 THEN split.String END),
    SGender   = MAX(CASE split.RN WHEN 8 THEN split.String END),
    SName     = MAX(CASE split.RN WHEN 9 THEN split.String END)
  FROM
  (
    SELECT      RN = 0, String = SUBSTRING(t.String,1,CHARINDEX(',',t.String)-1)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT      s.ItemNumber, clean.string
    FROM        (VALUES(t.string,CHARINDEX(',',t.String))) AS f(String,B)
    CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(f.String,CHAR(10))  AS s
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('":',s.item)))         AS d(Pos)
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(CHAR(13),s.item)))     AS v(E)
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(
                 s.item,d.Pos+3,v.E-d.Pos-5),'"','')))   AS clean(String)
    WHERE       d.Pos > 0
  ) AS split
) AS split;
```

**Returns:**

```
SomeId      StudentId     SLocs        SService        SUnit  SenZone  SGeoloc  SRegisted  SGender  SName     
----------- ------------- ------------ --------------- ------ -------- -------- ---------- -------- ---------
1           1             US,Kric      NY Volunteer    Band1  UTC      Ind      FT         Male     Sam
2           1             US,Chicago   Rock Star       Band4  XFS      Ill      PT         Female   Juliana
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to solve this, is to try to convert it to xml and parse that. something like the below:-

```
declare @d varchar(max)='1,{
"StudentLocs":["US","Kric"],
"Student_Service":["NY Volunteer"],
"Student_Unit":["Band1"],
"Student_enZone":["UTC"],
"Student_Geoloc":["Ind"],
"StudentRegisted":[FT"],
"StudentGender":["Male"],
"StudentName":["Sam"]
}'
```

Lets create a memory table to help in the convertion to xml, so we can make several replaces to original input.

```
Declare @replaceTable table(
id int identity(1,1),
item varchar(max), --item to find
[value] varchar(max) --item to replace with
)

insert into @replaceTable(item,[value]) values
(CHAR(13),''),(CHAR(10),''),
('StudentLocs:','</StudentId><StudentLocs>'),
('Student_Service:','</StudentLocs><Student_Service>'),
('Student_Unit:','</Student_Service><Student_Unit>'),
('Student_enZone:','</Student_Unit><Student_enZone>'),
('Student_Geoloc:','</Student_enZone><Student_Geoloc>'),
('StudentRegisted:','</Student_Geoloc><StudentRegisted>'),
('StudentGender:','</StudentRegisted><StudentGender>'),
('StudentName:','</StudentGender><StudentName>'),
('{',''),('}',''),('[',''),(']',''),('],',''),('"',''),(',{','')


declare @index int=(select COUNT(*) from @replaceTable)
set @d='<StudentId>'+@d+'</StudentName>' --some minor fix to the input

while(@index>0)--processing the replaces in desc order.
    select @d=REPLACE(@d,item,[value]) ,@index=@index-1 from @replaceTable where id=@index


Declare @xml xml=@d
    select 
    @xml.value('/StudentId[1]','int') StudentId,
    @xml.value('/StudentLocs[1]','varchar(max)') SLocs  ,
    @xml.value('/Student_Service[1]','varchar(max)') SService   ,
    @xml.value('/Student_Unit[1]','varchar(max)') SUnit ,
    @xml.value('/Student_enZone[1]','varchar(max)') SenZone ,
    @xml.value('/Student_Geoloc[1]','varchar(max)') SGeoloc,
    @xml.value('/StudentRegisted[1]','varchar(max)') SRegisted ,
    @xml.value('/StudentGender[1]','varchar(max)') SGender ,
    @xml.value('/StudentName[1]','varchar(max)') SName
```

The output will be as below:-

```
StudentId   SLocs   SService        SUnit   SenZone SGeoloc SRegisted   SGender SName
1           US,Kric NY Volunteer    Band1   UTC      Ind    FT           Male   Sam
```

Comment: This: "try to convert it to xml" will be more difficult than you expect, hard to debug and will perform notably worse than a set-based approach. While loops should be avoided at all costs and max datatypes (e.g. varchar(max)) should only be used when absolutely necessary. If you were to go with the XML approach you would also want to specify that you are going after a text node using the text() method. Example: `/StudentId[1]` should be `(/StudentId[1]/text())[1]`